# using awk to parse file that has 8 binary characters before CRLF

Tags: awk, binaryfiles

I am working on parsing a fixed-length file from a 3rd party where the last 8 bites of each line are not text, then there is a CRLF.  The following script is simply dumping the whole line.  I simply want to trip off the last 8 bytes before the CRLF, how do I do that?

```
BEGIN  { 
FIELDWIDTHS = "20 40 6 2 9 3 20 20 22"; 
FS="|";
}
{
    print $1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6 $7 $8 
}
```

Normally I provide some source data, but since it is binary and from a 3rd party such that I don't know if I have a legal right to give that data, I am at a loss for posting sample data.  What I know is that column 143 to 151 is binary, then there is the CRLF.

---

So the perl code works great!  But now the above script simply is not working, don't know why.  Here is three lines of the input:

```
ACCESSORIES         CAT                 NOI                 002070  A226C300N000Accessories:        Cat,                NOI                  
ACCESSORIES         DENTISTS                                056480  A226D532 000Accessories:        Dentists'                               v
ACCESSORIES         DOG                 NOI                 002070  A226D200N000Accessories:        Dog,                NOI
```

Answer (score 1):

Some Awks can probably cope, but it's not entirely portable.

Tiy

```sh
awk '{ sub(/.{8}\r$/,""}1' file
```

More portably, try Perl.

```sh
perl -pe 's/.{8}\r$//' file
```

Comment: The perl works great, but for reasons beyond me, the actual script isn't working with cleaner data.  I posted three lines of the data as an example.

Comment: Please update your Q with your sample data filtered thru `xxd`, ie `some_prog_that_can_extract_3_lines_to_std_out | xxd -u` . `sed -n '2,4p' file` might work, but given the mystery chars, and that the `awk` doesn't seem to work, it might not work. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Another awk, which keeps the CRLF ending:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {
    RS=ORS="\r\n"                   # handle the CRLF ending
}
{
    print substr($0,1,length()-8)   # print all but the last 8 chars
}' file
```